# Recovering a Partition with data on it

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning, data-recovery

So I stupidly deleted a partition when I was trying to join two partitions from the same disk together. It had been split up to a 100mb partition and the large hunk. This was my old drive that I used for my system os. However it kept the 100mb partition from that.

Anyways so I accidentally deleted the larger partition. Now I'm trying to recover that partition without losing any of the data that was on the drive. I have not formatted the drive and its just sitting there as Unallocated.

What I'm asking is how can I get this back to a usable partition without losing any data. ATM I'm trying to use AOMEI Partition Assistant, but its only bringing up the 100mb partition.

Is it possible to just re-allocate the partition with Disk Management and tell it not to format, would that keep my data in tact? Or is there something else that I need to do or you know of that would work?

Comment: Never tried it but I found this on YouTube after 2.46 seconds of Googling: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VgRamk_0ask

Comment: I've done a ton of googling myself, I wouldn't ask if I didn't. Which is why I used AOMEI... Don't assume I didn't use the all mighty google. I want to know what people have used and know to actually work.

Answer (score 0):

After some research I found [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk), and it seems like it might be what you're looking for. I'd encourage you to be very cautious when dealing w/ this kind of stuff, though, as I've had some past experience where trying to repair things can make the situation a lot worse. Best of luck!

As for your second question, no. :P

Comment: That didn't help me, still only came back with the 100mb partition. I'm using EaseUS Data Recovery to grab the data, then just re-partition the drive and throw it back on there.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you should not play around with the disk if you want to recover data. Use some recovery tools such as Recuva and recover the data. That is all there is to do.